# Link external function to C++20 Modules

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++20, c++-modules

I would like to reference a non-Module external (`extern`) function from within a C++ Module. Unfortunately using the normal method pre-Modules doesn't appear to work:

```
extern uint8_t* test(uint8_t*);
```

Produces this issue in Visual Studio 2022:

`error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "unsigned char * __cdecl test(unsigned char *)" (?test@@YAPEAEPEAE@Z::<!Module>)'`

Obviously I want it to look for `?test@@YAPEAEPEAE@Z` instead of `?test@@YAPEAEPEAE@Z::<!Module>`.

It appears Modules here name mangles differently. How do I convince the linker to look for a regular non-Module function from inside a Module?

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to **directly** declare such a function with

```
extern "C++" uint8_t* test(uint8_t*);
```

That said, this is mostly a curiosity and doesn’t work for functions declared by other (named) modules.  The **standard** solution is to `#include` (in the global module fragment) or `import` the declaration from elsewhere.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm looking for. Only with this change, using current Visual Studio, it's still looking for a function (mangled) signature with a `::<!Module>` at the end and does not successfully locate my function. Is this possibly a feature of Modules that Microsoft has not yet implemented in Visual Studio?

Comment: @Warpspace: Sounds like a compiler bug, yes.

Comment: @Warpspace
Hi, you can report the problem to [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/search?space=62). It is better to take the **standard solution** currently.

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with `extern` specifically.

If you declare a function inside of a module unit (unless it is in the global module fragment), then you're declaring that the function exists within the purview of that module. All declarations of such a function (including the *definition* of the function) must also be within the purview of that module. A module cannot export something to its interface which it does not own (unless it is owned by some other module which it `export import`s).

If you merely want to use that function within a module unit, then you should put that declaration in the global module fragment of the file.

Comment: It's good to know why the issue appeared, thanks. Would it be possible to edit your answer with an example solution. I did try placing my function declaration before the `export module Module;`, but with no success (only a warning saying `a global module fragment can only contain preprocessor directives`)